# Problems in custom element Polymer Facebook Plugin integration (javascript sdk)

Tags: javascript, facebook, polymer, polymer-starter-kit

I am fixing some features in my "polymer" site and I have a trouble with facebook page integration. I need to instantiate it by javascript as a result of clicking on a button. When I import facebook sdk by javascript I launch also FB.XFBML.parse() on my element, but nothing happens. No error. No rendering. How I can resolve it? Before I had used this facebook plugin directly in index.html and it had worked now i want to use it inside a custom element. ﻿

Comment: I think there is a problem with XFBML parser and shadow dom. Do you have in mind any workaround?

Comment: Do you have the same issue on a non-polymer site?